# Flipper plugins not working with react-native app

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler, react-native-debugger, react-native-hermes, fbflipper

I have react-native application in which I am using port 8383 port (I CAN NOT use default port 8081) for metro bundler. While debugging app with Flipper it's showing most of the plugins like Hermes/react dev-tool etc are not available.
After reading documentation, I believe using correct port for flipper should resolve it. If there is any other solution please let me know.

how can I update metro port for Flipper Mac app?

It's not clear how to follow instructions from link https://fbflipper.com/docs/custom-ports/ 
In which directory should I execute commands provided in link above?

I tried running `npx flipper-server --port 8383` in browser but it did not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As 8081 port was not available, I had to update Metro bundler port to 8383. After this I was not able to use Flipper plugins as Flipper was still referring to old Metro bundler port.

To fix this I created alias in .bash_profile

```
alias FlipperApp='env METRO_SERVER_PORT=8383 FLIPPER_PORTS=8383 /Applications/Flipper.app/Contents/MacOS/Flipper'
```

another alternative for Flipper Mac app is to use flipper in browser.

```
alias FlipperWeb='env METRO_SERVER_PORT=8383 npx flipper-server'
```

To launch flipper just used new alias and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer to the link you suggested. The document says as follows.

The execution path of these instructions is your project root path.

- Native interior setting. (your chosen ports 1111,2222 like so)

---

- Android

```sh
adb shell su 0 setprop flipper.ports 1111,2222
```

- IOS

```sh
xcrun simctl spawn booted defaults write "Apple Global Domain" "com.facebook.flipper.ports" -string "1111,2222"
```

- build setting

```sh
env FLIPPER_BROWSER_PORT=1111 yarn start or npm run start
```

Comment: Thanks @hong developer, I solved this problem before receiving this solution so couldn't try this one.